# Difference between dictionary and pandas series in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a requirement to keep data in key value pairs. I search and found 2 ways in python:

1. default data structure dictionary.

   ```
   x = {'key':value}
   value = x['key']
   ```
2. series of pandas data structure.

   ```
   x = pandas.Series({'key':value})
   value = x.key
   ```

I want to know the difference between this two apart from syntax.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html ?

Comment: A shoot into the dark: Dictonary is a base data structure, created by developer of Python. The developer of Pandas wraps a "different way" to create and access data on this structure. And they uses dictonary behind the stage.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *do* they use a dictionary in their internals?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Always read the docs first**
But since you asked:

- [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are one of python's default data structures which
  allow you to store `key: value` pairs and offer some built-in methods
  to manipulate your data, which you can read on the docs ([here is a
  good summary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) to jump start your reading process).
- [Panda's Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) are one-dimensional [ndarrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) with
  axis-labels, which allow you to store `array-like, dict, or scalar`
  values and are one of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s (a scientific computing python
  library) built-in data structures. 
  If you read the docs provided
  above (*see:* [Panda's Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) link) you will notice that they come with
  a vast amount of methods and attributes quite different, for the most
  part, from those of a python dictionary.

So it is not just a syntax difference to say the least.

If you only need to store some `key:value` pairs, your best and more elegant solution is to use the default dictionary. If you need to make some complex data manipulation on the stored data, then *consider* using panda's series.

Comment: Well, I have already read about it but not in deep. Your conclusion is really helpful, Thanks!

Comment: I actually favour the `s.x` notation over `d['x']` as more elegant (only 25% of the characters needed), and since I'm using Pandas heavily elsewhere, the Pandas.Series may be "best" for me.  Others who do a lot of numerical computing may agree.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 important differences.

1) Syntax and associated methods
    Allows for complex data manipulation in Panda series that would be difficult to achieve using a standard dictionary.

2) Order
    Standard python dictionaries are unordered sets; values can only be accessed by keys. Data in Panda series can be accessed by keys BUT can also be accessed with a numeric index because they are ordered.

In some ways, Panda series combine the best worlds of standard lists and standard dictionaries in python, but then top it off with some great data manipulation methods.